# Trying to make a triangle "*"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code, I don't know why it's not working..

```
shape = str(input("Type of Shape: "))

if(shape == "Triangle"):
    height  = int(input("Enter a height: "))
    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(i+1):
            print("*", end = " ")

elif(shape != "Rectangle" or shape != "Triangle"):
    print("Unavailable shape, ask for valid shape")
```

if you run the program and type in Triangle and type in a height like 5, it's printing out :

```
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

I'm using Python 3.6.3 so I don't know if that plays a huge role in this.

Comment: You should add newlines (with `print()`).

Comment: What did you expect instead? That's exactly what you asked for; it's printed a bunch of asterisks each followed by a space. Also note your elif condition would always be true; just use else.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/programs-printing-pyramid-patterns-python/: Check this..It has your requirement

Comment: add a new line using `print("\n")` just outside the end of the inner `for` loop

Answer (score 1):

You can replace inner for loop with following one line
`print("*"*(i+1))`